# Partial html view's controller not working in Directive TemplateUrl using KendoPanelBar contenturl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

**Directive**

```
app.directive('PanelbarDirective', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        templateUrl: 'ngview/shared/panelbar.html'

    };
});
```

**testcontroller.js**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('testcontroller', ['$scope',
function testcontroller($scope) {
    $scope.LabelValue = 'From Controller';

}]);
```

**panelbar.html**

```
<div id="selected-values" class="col-sm-12 colSlctdValues" >
    <ul id="panelbar"></ul>

    <script>
        $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
            dataSource: [
                {
                    text: "Teachers",
                    expanded: true,
                    contentUrl: "ngview/shared/Teachers.html"
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>


</div>
```

**Teachers.html**

```
<table ng-controller="testcontroller">
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>{{LabelValue}}</td>            
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>
```

What problem i am facing is, it is always displaying value {{LabelValue}} instead of what i have assigned value to LabelValue in controller of partial view.

Answer (score 0):

It has only issue when i try to implement this using javascript in
**panelbar.html**

```
<script>
    $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
        dataSource: [
            {
                text: "Teachers",
                expanded: true,
                contentUrl: "ngview/shared/Teachers.html"
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

however i **fixed** this using

```
    <ul id="panelbar" kendo-panel-bar  k-options="panelBarOptions">
        <li>
            Teachers
            <ul>
                <li ng-include="'ngview/shared/Teachers.html'"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Would love to know if anyone still can **help me to do using script** instead of **ul** and **ng-include**.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

see this [kendo official page examples](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/panelbar/ajax)

```
    <div id="example">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul id="panelbar">
                <li>
                    BODY
                    <div></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    ENGINE
                    <div></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    TRANSMISSION
                    <div></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    PERFORMANCE
                    <div></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
                expandMode: "single",
                contentUrls: [
                    '../content/web/panelbar/ajax/ajaxContent1.html',
                    '../content/web/panelbar/ajax/ajaxContent2.html',
                    '../content/web/panelbar/ajax/ajaxContent3.html',
                    '../content/web/panelbar/ajax/ajaxContent4.html'
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .wrapper {
            height: 320px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            padding: 20px 0 0;
            background: url('../content/web/panelbar/astonmartin.png') no-repeat center 50px transparent;
        }
        #panelbar {
            width: 250px;
            float: right;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        #panelbar p {
            padding: 1em;
        }
    </style>
```

This part of code is copy-pasted of link content from KendoUI page in case that link change

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)